# How would I pass a variable into Jenkins which contains wildcards?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to build a jar and include specific files:

```
jar cf models.jar target/classes/**/models
```

However, I am making a pipeline with variables:

```
jar cf ${JAR_NAME}.jar ${FILE_SEARCH_PATTERN}
```

This causes the command to run as:

```
jar cf models.jar 'target/classes/**/models'
```

which causes the system to not find any files as the quotes break the search.

Comment: You should pass it as something other than a String.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem; while it doesn't get around how the groovy script is translated in Jenkins, this might help people trying to achieve something similar.

```
# in project Jenkinsfile
file_search_path = "target/classes/.*/models/.*\\.class"

# in library Jenkinsfile
files=\$(find . -print | grep -i ${FILE_SEARCH_PATH})
jar cf ${JAR_NAME}.jar \$files
```

[Here is a link to the full version of the code.](https://gist.github.com/alyons/31438d2c84b54a4f4871332fa8332e92)